# Jquery onclick var update

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

This is a very simple, probably too simple question but I'm afraid my limited skills in jQuery require someone's help!
Behold the shameful line of code:

```
onclick="javascript:  $j('#'+openc).fadeOut('normal', function({
$j('#'+openc).fadeIn('slow')});
openc=+1;
alert('The city of ' + openc + ' is located in ' + openc + '.');"
```

By default, openc is set to 0.

Onclick, the div with the id 0 is faded out, and I wish to have div id 1 open, then openc to b updated to 1. I added the alert for my own sake. When I press once, it seems to work. When I press it again, it still alerts 1, thus my div id 1 fades out and right back in.
I think I just need to add +1 to the fadeIn function with the onclick, so that it will always open openc+1 but..can't seem to get the syntax right.

Thanks!

EDIT: Perhaps my question was not clear enough, I figured I would add some info. I beg you to not suggest things such as adding event-handlers, I have no clue what that even means, I am a total noob at javascript/jQuery. All I need to do is this:

onclick, fadeout the div openc (which yes, is a number) ,fadein openc +1, and update openc to its own value +1.

This is for a pagination of sorts between divs.
So say you land on div id=0, openc=0. You click on next, it should fadeout div0, fadein div1, and openc should now equal1. That way, the next time you click next, div1 fades out, and div2 appears, etc.

Hope that clarifies, thanks again!

Comment: i think the complete code example would help, maybe use http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you using the `onclick` attribute of an element to assign a click event handler? Also, the [W3C standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name) state that IDs must begin with a letter ([a-zA-Z]).

Comment: Don't use "javascript:" in onclick. It is redundant.

Comment: In addition to that, it's `+=` rather than `=+` to perform addition and assignment using the single operator. The code is very difficult to read in its current state, but I did spot that.

Comment: Anthony, thank you, you're the only one who actually answered my question rather than tell me what's wrong with my code. I am aware that it is horrible to read, and deprecated and what-have-you, I suck at javascript/jQuery, and the fact that I can't even make a simple addition should tell a lot on the fact that I have no clue what's good practice or not lol! I'll try this Anthony, thx again.

Comment: @Diodeus: Actually, it does something completely different: It defines a label which is a no-op in this case since labels are only useful in `switch` bodies in JavaScript.

Comment: So, in this case, what is its purpose?

Comment: Anthony, I tried and actually the =+1 worked fine, I'm looking to update my openc var to its own value + 1..At the same time as openingup the associated div id?

Comment: @Sherif It's valid syntax, but it's not what you want. `openc += 1` saves the value of `openc + 1` back into the `openc` variable. `openc=+1` saves the value of `+1` into the `openc` variable. That's why your first click worked, but subsequent ones didn't, as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Makes sense Anthony, thanks for the clarification! In any case, switching to your suggested openc +=1 didn't seem to work either, my alert shows 01 rather than just "1"! I updated the project detail btw.

Comment: I assumed your `openc` variable was a number (`var openc = 0`), but apparently it's a string (`var openc = '0'`). In that case `+=` will result in string concatenation, rather than arithmetic addition, which is why you get `01` rather than the desired `1`.

Comment: Oh! Gotcha! Works now, thanks a bunch! Now, to actually fadeIn openc+1, I tried doing `$j('#'+openc += 1).fadeIn('slow')});` but that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this code in to an event handler, rather than use the outdated `onclick` HTML attribute. Try putting this in to the `<head>` of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $j("#myElement").click(function() {
            $j('#' + openc).fadeOut('normal', function() {
                $j('#' + openc).fadeIn('slow')
            });

            openc += 1;

            alert('The city of ' + openc + ' is located in ' + openc + '.');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, as stated in the comments Ids cannot start with numbers, so it'd be best to change those too.

Comment: +1 - you answer would've been even nicer if you had wrapped it with `(function($){ ... })($j);` to use `$` insisde. ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Oh man, I always forget to add something in my answers lately! Thanks.

Comment: I'd love to give this a try, but I honestly have no clue what I'd have to change to make this work. Besides, I would much rather not have to put anything in the head of the site, this code needs to work only on one page and I'm worried it might cause conflict with other scripts on the rest of the site. Can you kindly simply tell me how to do it with my onclick function, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to have code which is that involved in the `onclick` attribute. Normally it's for specifying a function name to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

`openc=+1` makes it look line "openc" is a number. IDs cannot be numbers.

Comment: openc is indeed a number, so are the divs. Why can't it be numbers?

Comment: Because the w3c spec says so.

Comment: How else do you suggest I make a Prev/Next nav based on preloaded divs, allhidden, not knowing how many I'll have in advance? I appreciate your answer but my question is not "how can I make my page w3c compliant", it is simply how can I update the value of my openc var to its own value +1 , on click ;)

Comment: You count them using $('#myDIV').length and navigate them using relative selectors like .next()

Comment: That sounds like the perfect solution, but as I mentionned in my post, I have no clue what I'm doing here..I realize I'm asking for a cheap solution, but javascript is not my field, at all, and I cannot invest in learning it for such a small task, which, other than the w3c compliance, works fine! I'd really appreciate if you could simply let me know how to update the openc var, onclick, I'd be much obliged!